# Has there been a theory of intermediate truth values based on the number of conjuncts that are true?

Tags: logic, reference-request

Has anyone written about a theory of intermediate truth values based on the following lines: Suppose we have $n$ elementary statements $A_1,...,A_n$. If there are exactly $k$ true statements among them, the truth value of the conjunction $A_1 \land ... \land A_n$ is $k/n$. So for example, if $A_1 := 2<3$, $A_2:= 2+3=5$ and $A_3:= 3+3=4$, then the conjunction $A_1 \land A_2 \land A_3$ has a truth value of $2/3$. I know there are logics which have truth values any real number between $0$ and $1$, but I am specifically asking if someone in some text or paper have come up with something very similar to what I have come up with.

Comment: Check out the following paper "Isn't Every Sufficiently Complex Logic Multi-Valued Already: Lindenbaum-Tarski Algebra and Fuzzy Logic are Both Particular Cases of the Same Idea"

Comment: Such a system is not [truth-functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_function) (because the truth value of $A\land B$ isn't determined by the truth values of $A$ and $B$) and therefore isn't like [most fuzzy logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-norm_fuzzy_logics). How do you propose extending your definition to propositions with other logical connectives? It seems tricky to get something consistent that could be construed as a logic, but I guess this depends on which properties you want it to have.